# an undefined variable in node.js with the mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
let customer_count;
let cust_string;
Customer.count({}, function(err, count){ customer_count = count+1; cust_string = 'cust' + customer_count });

        // Create a customer object with escaped and trimmed data.
        var customer = new Customer(
          { customerId: cust_string})
```

I would like to make a self-defined customer id for my model's index. I want that id looks like 'cust0001' something and the next one will be 'cust0002'. So, I used the count() from mongoose to join the string but unforunately, when I am creating the customer object, the 'cust_string' is said to be undefined. Could you please help me fix it?

Comment: Callback doesn't return anything. You have to create customer inside the same function you're calculating `cust_string`. Other option is to use promises/async/await

Answer (score 0):

Callback doesn't return anything. You have to create customer inside the same function you're calculating `cust_string`. Other option is to use promises/async/await etc.

Your code will work this way:

```
let customer_count;
let cust_string;

Customer.count({}, function (err, count) {
    // calculate id
    customer_count = count + 1;
    cust_string = 'cust' + customer_count;

    // Create a customer object
    var customer = new Customer({ customerId: cust_string });
});
```

But this is not a good way to implement auto-increment in mongodb. It will be very expensive operation.

I recommend you to use [mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment). It saves sequences in database and prevents duplicate keys.